# JPQL Foreign Key as condition in NamedQuery()?

Tags: jpa, key, constraints, jpql

I want to realize two tables, table one has OnToMany and Table two is ManyToOne (so we have a 1 : N relation). Solution: Avoid reserved words.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your JPA provider does not automatically quote SQL reserved words for you (ORDER) and so the RDBMS is objecting to the SQL thrown at it.

If that is the case (easily checked, can you do a simple query with no WHERE clause?) then you'll have to set the table name as 'ORDER', or change its name to a non-keyword, or use a JPA provider that does auto-quote such things for you (e.g DataNucleus JPA).

Comment: you are totally right! I didn't consider it. But If I do 'Order' it will say "unknown table/entity.."

Comment: I got it. I just put a table annotation with \"name\".